# What are 'symmetric (or 'new age') ring structures'?

Tags: ring-theory, terminology

The title says it: what are 'symmetric (or 'new age') ring structures'?

The phrase was found in:
Frank Quinn, Contributions to a Science of Contemporary Mathematics (Draft October 4, 2011),
p 74 (link: http://www.math.vt.edu/people/quinn/history_nature/nature0.pdf).

What's he talking about?

Comment: I think they appeared in a paper by [Yanni](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yanni).

Comment: @rschwieb That 'Yanni' link refers to a page about a musician. Is that what you intended?

Comment: I suspect what is meant is homotopy algebra, also known as "brave new algebra". For example, there are [$A_\infty$-rings](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/A-infinity-ring).

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, it was intended to be a joke incorporating the most famous New Age musician I could think of :) Sorry if the levity was not welcome!